# Search: Do not index some parts of HTML

Tags: 8, search

We're indexing the rendered HTML output (`rendered_item`, type "Fulltext") of pages into elasticsearch using elasticsearch_connector.

Some parts of the HTML shall not be indexed because they contain automatically generated teaser elements for other content.

TYPO3 lets one define the parts of the HTML content to be included by adding [HTML comment markers](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/10.4/en-us/TechnicalDetails/HtmlContent/Index.html):

```
<html>
 <body>
  <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->
   relevant content
  <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->
  irrelevant content
 </body>
</html>
```

Does such a thing exist for Drupal's search indexer, too? Or do I have to write my own [search processor](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/getting-started/processors)?